# MySQL Galera node not starting (aborting with Error 'WSREP: [...]: 60: failed to reach primary view: 60 (Operation timed out)')

Tags: mysql, unix, freebsd, galera

I am trying to setup three Galera nodes on FreeBSD 10 with MySQL 5.6.26 and VirtualBox. When I set up everything and run MySQL, it exits after some time and cannot start properly.

Here is my log:

```
2015-10-22 15:23:24 9402 [Note] WSREP: Read nil XID from storage engines, skipping position init
2015-10-22 15:23:24 9402 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): loading provider library '/usr/local/lib/libgalera_smm.so'
2015-10-22 15:23:24 9402 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): Galera 3.5(rXXXX) by Codership Oy <info@codership.com> loaded successfully.
2015-10-22 15:23:24 9402 [Note] WSREP: CRC-32C: using "slicing-by-8" algorithm.
2015-10-22 15:23:24 9402 [Note] WSREP: Found saved state: 9bfd9448-780a-11e5-a465-e268e80baf6e:-1
2015-10-22 15:23:24 9402 [Note] WSREP: Passing config to GCS: base_host = 192.168.1.10; base_port = 4567; cert.log_conflicts = no; debug = no; evs.inactive_check_period = PT0.5S; evs.inactive_timeout = PT15S; evs.join_retrans_period = PT1S; evs.max_install_timeouts = 1; evs.send_window = 4; evs.stats_report_period = PT1M; evs.suspect_timeout = PT5S; evs.user_send_window = 2; evs.view_forget_timeout = PT24H; gcache.dir = /home/mysql/; gcache.keep_pages_size = 0; gcache.mem_size = 0; gcache.name = /home/mysql//galera.cache; gcache.page_size = 128M; gcache.size = 128M; gcs.fc_debug = 0; gcs.fc_factor = 1.0; gcs.fc_limit = 16; gcs.fc_master_slave = no; gcs.max_packet_size = 64500; gcs.max_throttle = 0.25; gcs.recv_q_hard_limit = 9223372036854775807; gcs.recv_q_soft_limit = 0.25; gcs.sync_donor = no; gmcast.listen_addr = 192.168.1.10; gmcast.segment = 0; gmcast.version = 0; ist.recv_addr = 192.168.1.10; pc.announce_timeout = PT3S; pc.checksum = false; pc.ignore_quorum = false; pc.ignore_sb = false; pc.npvo = false; pc.version = 0; pc.wait_prim 
2015-10-22 15:23:24 9402 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
2015-10-22 15:23:24 9402 [Note] WSREP: Assign initial position for certification: 4, protocol version: -1
2015-10-22 15:23:24 9402 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_sst_grab()
2015-10-22 15:23:24 9402 [Note] WSREP: Start replication
2015-10-22 15:23:24 9402 [Note] WSREP: Setting initial position to 9bfd9448-780a-11e5-a465-e268e80baf6e:4
2015-10-22 15:23:24 9402 [Note] WSREP: protonet asio version 0
2015-10-22 15:23:24 9402 [Note] WSREP: Using CRC-32C (optimized) for message checksums.
2015-10-22 15:23:24 9402 [Note] WSREP: backend: asio
2015-10-22 15:23:24 9402 [Note] WSREP: GMCast version 0
2015-10-22 15:23:24 9402 [Note] WSREP: (b08a4d6e-78b7-11e5-80bf-12866e73025e, 'tcp://192.168.1.10:4567') listening at tcp://192.168.1.10:4567
2015-10-22 15:23:24 9402 [Note] WSREP: (b08a4d6e-78b7-11e5-80bf-12866e73025e, 'tcp://192.168.1.10:4567') multicast: , ttl: 1
2015-10-22 15:23:24 9402 [Note] WSREP: EVS version 0
2015-10-22 15:23:24 9402 [Note] WSREP: PC version 0
2015-10-22 15:23:24 9402 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: connecting to group 'test', peer '192.168.1.10:,192.168.1.20:,192.168.1.30:'
2015-10-22 15:23:27 9402 [Warning] WSREP: no nodes coming from prim view, prim not possible
2015-10-22 15:23:27 9402 [Note] WSREP: view(view_id(NON_PRIM,b08a4d6e-78b7-11e5-80bf-12866e73025e,1) memb {
    b08a4d6e-78b7-11e5-80bf-12866e73025e,0
} joined {
} left {
} partitioned {
})
2015-10-22 15:23:27 9402 [Warning] WSREP: last inactive check more than PT1.5S ago (PT3.6479S), skipping check
2015-10-22 15:23:57 9402 [Note] WSREP: view((empty))
2015-10-22 15:23:57 9402 [ERROR] WSREP: failed to open gcomm backend connection: 60: failed to reach primary view: 60 (Operation timed out)
     at gcomm/src/pc.cpp:connect():141
2015-10-22 15:23:57 9402 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs_core.c:gcs_core_open():202: Failed to open backend connection: -60 (Operation timed out)
2015-10-22 15:23:57 9402 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs.c:gcs_open():1291: Failed to open channel 'test' at 'gcomm://192.168.1.10,192.168.1.20,192.168.1.30': -60 (Operation timed out)
2015-10-22 15:23:57 9402 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs connect failed: Operation timed out
2015-10-22 15:23:57 9402 [ERROR] WSREP: wsrep::connect(gcomm://192.168.1.10,192.168.1.20,192.168.1.30) failed: 7
2015-10-22 15:23:57 9402 [ERROR] Aborting

2015-10-22 15:23:57 9402 [Note] WSREP: Service disconnected.
2015-10-22 15:23:58 9402 [Note] WSREP: Some threads may fail to exit.
2015-10-22 15:23:58 9402 [Note] Binlog end
2015-10-22 15:23:58 9402 [Note] /usr/local/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

151022 15:23:58 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /home/mysql/galera1.pid ended
```

Part of `my.cnf` regarding wsrep config:

```
wsrep_provider=/usr/local/lib/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_name="test"
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://192.168.1.10,192.168.1.20,192.168.1.30"
wsrep_slave_threads=8
wsrep_node_address = "192.168.1.10"
wsrep_sst_receive_address = "192.168.1.10"
wsrep_node_incoming_address = "192.168.1.10"
wsrep_provider_options = "gmcast.listen_addr=192.168.1.10;gcache.size=128M;ist.recv_addr=192.168.1.10"
wsrep_auto_increment_control=1
wsrep_retry_autocommit=0
wsrep_max_ws_size=3741824
wsrep_max_ws_rows=56000
wsrep_certify_nonPK=1
wsrep_convert_LOCK_to_trx=0
wsrep_sst_donor=galera1
wsrep_sst_donor_rejects_queries=1
```

- Node 1 - 192.168.1.10
- Node 2 - 192.168.1.20
- Node 3 - 192.168.1.30

The above output is from node 1.

The networking between the nodes is working properly, so I can't seem to find a reason for this not to work.

Comment: I fixed grammar and spelling a bit and made sure the log and config file aren't syntax-highlighted as SQL code. I also included part of the first ERROR from your log in the question title, so more people with knowledge of the subject will notice it.

Answer (score 10):

Make sure you start the first node by running the following command:

```sh
service mysql start --wsrep-new-cluster
```

Start the next nodes by running the command:

```sh
service mysql start
```

I get exactly the same errors as your when I forget to add the param --wsrep-new-cluster when I start the first node.

Check this page for details: [Starting the cluster](http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/startingcluster.html)

Just a quick edit: I personally use Galera with MariaDB and the commands above work properly. As you use MySQL, you might need to switch `mysql` with `mysqld` in the commands above. Try with both.

Comment: I had to edit the grastate.dat file manually to get this to work, posted my solution on another related thread since it seems to get more views and it was the same issue. Thought I'd post the URL here to kinda "link" the two issues. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127115/mariadb-galera-cluster-set-up-problems/41352131#41352131